# Spring boot - Parent and Child have different main methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having some issues while deploying application on tomcat. The thing is when i deploy application from Child project then it works fine whereas 
if i run application from parent project, it doesn't load the application properly. And i saw some exceptions on tomcat console like 
Tomcat is bind etc.

My question - is this possible that both application (parent and child) applications have its own Application.Java classes since child project is added as dependency in parent project?

if i kill the java process then it loads only parent application but not application and when i stop the tomcat server and run it again same tomcat port exception comes again.

**Parent Project**
**Example.Java**

```
@RequestMapping("/test/**")
@RestController
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
  @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class HelloWorldApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
        }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.pos.interfaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.pos.dashboard.backend.HelloWorldApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jira-widget-app</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-widget-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Child Project**
**Example.java**

```
package com.jira.pos.widget;
@RequestMapping("/tester/**")
@RestController
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

HelloWorldApplication1 .java

```
  package com.jira.pos.widget;
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class HelloWorldApplication1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication1.class, args);
        }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.pos.interfaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.jira.pos.widget.HelloWorldApplication1</start-class>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Moreover, Both projects have their own services, jsps and main methods etc. Any idea how can i get rid off this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand the problem exactly from your question but I "think" that both apps are being registered with Tomcat which then tries to start them both and since they're both started with the default port, which is 8080, this is probably why you're getting the port binding exception.

Have you tried setting the property server.port in the src/main/resources/application.properties of both parent and child to two different values, e.g. parent on 8282 and child on 8585 and see if the problem persists?